# Linear Layout Constraints added automatically when switching tabs

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

Android Studio keeps changing my constrains when switching tabs between `Design` and `Text` tabs.

Before changing to `Design` tab:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">....
```

After switching to `Design` and back to `Text`:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="587dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">...
```

Must be a button I am missing. How do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: May be you are adding any widget from design panel that affects your layout.

Comment: Nope, no widget adding. New Empty Activity. Only Linear Layout with TextView or ImageView added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a bug in Android Studio.

Once I upgraded to `3.0.1` the problem seemed to be resolved itself.